# Spark Streaming Kafka Issue

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I am new to Spark and Kafka Integration and I am facing strange issue.

Code is working perfectly in local machine and when I ran same in production, data is not writing to elastisearch.

I am not sure whether data is reading from the kafka and parsing to write it to elasticsearch. I am not able to verify the data with println statements as I am running in cluster mode and not able to see the DStream[String]. Here is the DStream how I defined and passing the variables to it.

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> config.getString("bootstrap.servers"),
      "zookeeper.connect" -> config.getString("zookeeper.connect"),
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> config.getString("zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms"),
      "security.protocol" -> config.getString("security.protocol"),
      "auto.offset.reset" -> config.getString("auto.offset.reset"),
      "group.id" -> config.getString("consumer.group.id")

    )
var message_raw = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,kafkaParams,topicConfiguration).map(row=> row._2)
```

As it is working in test environment, I am not sure what I am missing in production cluster mode.

Please provide any thoughts which may be helpful for my investigation.

Thanks, Bab

Comment: If the goal is to take data from Kafka to Elasticsearch, I would suggest using Kafka Connect rather than writing your own Spark code